# What's the meaning of "I've got an end darter down on six" in The Pink Panther?

Tags: meaning

In the movie *The Pink Panther,* during the scene of Clouseau's bag full of weapons, the person that checked the bag later says "I've got an end darter down on six". What's the meaning of the phrase?

Here's the context:

*Inspector Clouseau is at an airport surrounded by police officers:*

> IC: I'm simply telling you I have a couple of "tamburthers."
>   PO2: I've got an End darter down on six. I've got an End darter down on six!
>   PO2: Locked and loaded, sir!
>   PO3: Show me your hands, sir!

And [here's the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rt_5lkN_BE) (4:07)

Comment: I think it's some kind of "dodger", but can't tell for sure.

Comment: I think that's the joke: the guard's English is as incomprehensible as Clouseau's French.

Comment: "Tamburthers" is "hamburgers".  I have no idea what the PO2 is saying.

Comment: For what it is worth, [this site](http://www.houzz.se/photos/80310/mountain-retreat-rustik-fasad-other-metro) uses it as edge of a house when describing it.

Comment: @Hot Licks, what's a dodger?

Comment: @Dan Shaffer--did you notice that your site is primarily in some Nordic language..could be Swedish, could be Danish, I'm no expert...

Comment: @KristinaLopez - PO2 is perhaps saying that there is an extremist on lane 6.

Comment: @Graffito Why do you say so? Incidentally, in the Spanish version "End dodger" is translated as "extremist".

Comment: @user152435 - Someone who dodges.  Beyond that I have no idea.

Comment: FWIW, in the Portuguese version "end dodger" is translated as "suspected terrorist".

Comment: In French sub-tiltes, it is "we have a problem on checkpoint 6".

Comment: So. an end darter means......?

Comment: Perhaps the unfunniest Clouseau ever... no wonder Steve Martin received scathing reviews.  The security guard is merely repeating what he *thinks* Clouseau is saying, the Frenchman is saying he has a couple of hamburgers, and the security guy imitates the nonsensical pronunciation *an darter*.  Why the storm of guards appear suddenly is probably dictated by the outlawed contents found in the inspector's hand luggage.

Comment: I'm going to guess an end-darter is one who darts around the end...of the security checkpoint line presumably.

Comment: There are lines to go through customs; Line 6 has someone darting away at the end of that particular line? I dunno what those machines are called where you place your luggage for inspection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an acronym peculiar to the TSA or NHS. I looked over the lists of acronyms for both agencies and couldn't find anything that worked. [National Capital Region Homeland Security Program: Acronyms and Glossary of Terms](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219134010/http://www.ncrhomelandsecurity.org/ncr/glossary.asp) and also [Sensors Directorate Acronyms Listing](https://web.archive.org/web/20100618033521/http://www.fas.org/news/reference/acronym.htm).

Answer (score -1):

A darter is an air to air missile.

Wikipedia gives an example of an [A Darter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-Darter)

> The V3E A-Darter (Agile Darter) is a modern short-range infrared homing ("heat seeking") air-to-air missile
>
> An air-to-air missile (AAM) is a missile fired from an aircraft for
> the purpose of destroying another aircraft. AAMs are typically powered
> by one or more rocket motors, usually solid fueled but sometimes
> liquid fueled.

Comment: This seems unlikely to be the intended meaning given the context.